# Finding records where the current time is x pm in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I am using active support to find time zones where it is x pm.

```
time_zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select{ |time| time.now.hour == x }
```

Then find records in that time zone.

```
Record.where(time_zone: time_zones)
```

The time_zone in these records is set using the Geocoder gem (Geocoder.search("ip_addr")). The problem is that Geocoder gives a time_zone value like "Asia/Thimphu" but there is no such value in the ActiveSupport list([refer_this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)). In my record search, it is possible that it will skip records with time zone not listed in the ActiveSupport list despite being x pm in there.

Would be grateful of any solutions.

Comment: If you want to select times where the current time is PM you want `time_zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select{ |time| time.now.stftime('%p') == "PM" }`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @max. I meant "x PM" as an example. What I actually meant was looking for time zones where it was a certain specific time in that zone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the constant `MAPPING` in [TimeZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) class to get the `TZInfo identifier` from Rails timezone name.

```
zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |zone| zone.now.hour == x }
zone_identifiers = zones.map { |zone| ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING[zone.name] }

Record.where(time_zone: zone_identifiers)
```

**Update from comments**

Also you could still save the record and get the identifiers using the mapping though:

```
zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |zone| zone.now.hour == x }
zone_identifiers = zones.map { |zone| IANA_TO_ACTIVERECORD_BULLSHIT_TIMEZONE_MAPPING.filter_map { |k, v| k if v == zone.name } }.flatten

Record.where(time_zone: zone_identifiers)
```

but definitely cleaner to keep the Rails timezone names in the database.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, "Asia/Thimphu" will not get included in the query that fetches zones. On the other hand, ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING has the same list of timezones as ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all. I am considering using a different mapping (https://gist.github.com/jpmckinney/767070) to save the timezone name in the record so that the whole of the database will only contain the time zones supported by active support.

Comment: ah, you are right. I misread your question as not able to find the TZinfo identifier. `Asia/Thimphu` would be same as `Asia/Dhaka` but we might need a mapping like you mentioned

I think Rails decided not to map all Tzinfo identifiers to their timezones.  In the comments, they say https://gist.github.com/stevelacey/0c8656a0129b415843b0 is more accurate though. (`IANA_TO_ACTIVERECORD_BULLSHIT_TIMEZONE_MAPPING` lol)

edited answer with another possible alternative, while keeping tzinfo timezones in the database, but definitely cleaner to save the Rails timezone directly in the database